# Installing latest version of Open Shift locally

Tags: vagrant, openshift

I have successfully installed Open Shift locally on my Ubuntu laptop using this guide:

https://blog.openshift.com/using-openshift-3-on-your-local-environment/

using this vagrant file:
https://www.openshift.org/vm/Vagrantfile

But its a fairly old version, 1.2.0:

[image]

https://app.vagrantup.com/thesteve0/boxes/openshift-origin

Any suggestion on how to update to e.g. latest or 3.6/3.7 using the above guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an old guide for deploying OpenShift locally. They have switched to using [Minishift](https://www.openshift.org/minishift/) for local development. I recommend giving that a try for a more up to date environment!

Answer (score 0):

Here docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/install_config/upgrading/automated_upgrades.html#install-config-upgrading-automated-upgrades it's an article about how you can automatically upgrade the openshift. I hope this will help You!